# Mule 3 in Debug Mode - how do I view payload as JSON?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule-el

So this question is specific while running Anypoint Studio 6.x ( 6.6.10 ) in debug mode ( Mule 3 )
Now as a part of the implementation many a times the payload or variables are stored in format `application/java` which while debugging makes it difficult to visualise the data .

In case of Mule 4 in debugger I can simply enter the dataweave :

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

However this is not possible in Mule 3 , infact you cannot even enter a command spanning multiple lines

so question is - how to view payload in debug mode in json format in case of Mule3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mule 4 uses DataWeave 2 as its expression language. Mule 3 used [MEL](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/mule-expression-language-mel) expressions. MEL doesn't directly supports JSON. You could try executing a DataWeave 1 transformation from MEL using the [dw() function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/mel-dataweave-functions#the-dw-function) to convert the payload to JSON.

```java
dw("payload","application/json")
```

I don't have a Studio 6 environment to test it right now.